# Editing data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I just began to study angular, tried to make some kind of SPA, but faced with problem of editing data in it. The obect is visible in console, but it hasn't appear on page, what I did wrong?
Here my controller:

```
var app = angular.module("testModule", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'addCtrl'
    })
    .when('/save', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/save.html',
        controller: 'editCtrl'
    })
    .when('/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/edit.html',
        controller: 'addCtrl'
    })
})

app.service('dataService', function($http) {
  var data = {};
  data.list = [];
  var getData = function() {
     $http.get("model/data.json").then(function (response) {
      data.list = response.data;
    });
  }
  return {
    getDataFromJson: getData,
    getData: data,
  }
});

app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, dataService) {
    dataService.getDataFromJson();  
});

app.controller("editCtrl", function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.data = dataService.getData;

  $scope.editData = function(adverse){
    $scope.adverse= adverse;
    console.log($scope.adverse)
  }
});
```

and the part of page:

```
<div class="panel">
    <form name="addForm" >
        <div class="well" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type='text' id="name" class="form-control" ng-model="adverse.name" placeholder={{adverse.name}} />
                <label for="shop">Shop:</label>
                <input type='text' id="shop" class="form-control" ng-model="adverse.shop" placeholder="{{adverse.shop}}" />
                <label for="begin">Begin:</label>
                <input id="begin" class="form-control" ng-model="adverse.begin" placeholder="{{adverse.begin}}" >
                <label for="end">End:</label>
                <input id="end" class="form-control" ng-model="adverse.end" placeholder="{{adverse.end}}" />   
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block add_btn" ng-click="editData(adverse)">
                    <a href="#/">Edit</a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Also here is a screenshot: the props of object suppose to be in the inputs but it hasn't.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqhGU.png)

If possible can you give me an example how I can do it by another way?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Are you trying to prefill your input?

Comment: F12 , any errors?     be sure to have spa main html page have reference to controller etc..

Answer (score 0):

Recreated your scenario in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wn2xQOckDhokp6SaXUD?p=preview) plunker. But it works. Please have a look at this plunker where you alo can see the *StateProvider* which is used instead of *NgRoute*

One thing I see which is incorrect is that you are sending the adverse object in the function and then setting the param to the scope adverse.
The thing is that the $scope.adverse already holds the values so you don't need to pass the value and setting it to the scope again. Remeber the scope is your glue between the view and ctrl

```
$scope.editData = function(){
    console.log($scope.adverse)
}
```